# Detecting Nokia E61 Keyboard Layout in J2ME

Tags: nokia, java-me

Nokia E61,E71 etc has different variations of keyboard layouts like QWERTY, QWERTZ , AZERTY etc. Is there a way I could detect the current keyboard layout through J2ME?

And there is also some funny thing happening, some E61 we tested has QWERTY keypad but is running QWERTZ layout pre-installed. Is anyone aware of such issues?

Comment: Why do you need that? a key should give you the same key code in java regardless of where it is physically located on the device.

Comment: Maybe the OP wants to make a game or something that requires keys to be in a set physical pattern.  If so, best solution for this would be to simply ask the user to select current layout!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are going to be able to find out what the physical keypad layout is unless Nokia encoded a pattern into the "microedition.platform" System property. I couldn't find any.

If the physical key is sending the wrong key code to java, I would expect it to also behave badly in native applications and the one reason I can see for this would be that the handset contains the wrong version of the firmware (The physical handset is localized for one region and the firmware is localized for a different region).

Comment: Yeah you are right, the key code is returned correctly, And moreover if the user has a wrong firmware, let him update to the correct one.